# Fix corrupted NTFS files system?

Tags: windows-7, ntfs, repair

I was copying some files over to my RAID (Drobo) connected to my Win7x64 computer and it hung up so i tried to cancel and restarting but when i restarted the computer as soon as it recognized the drobo it said that i needed to run chkdsk. So I have tried numerous times at first getting slight different responses but now it just tells me the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>chkdsk e: /x
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is Drobo.

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  389888 file records processed.
File verification completed.
  53 large file records processed.
  0 bad file records processed.
  0 EA records processed.
  0 reparse records processed.

CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
73 percent complete. (385929 of 400400 index entries processed)
Deleting index entry found.000 in index $I30 of file 5.
  400400 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
CHKDSK is scanning unindexed files for reconnect to their original directory.
  991 unindexed files scanned.
CHKDSK is recovering remaining unindexed files.
75 percent complete. (1 of 996 unindexed files recovered)
```

I know exactly which directory/sub-directories are causing the problem but of course i can't seem to delete them either. I tried contacting Drobo but they were characteristically unhelpful (have tried contacting them before for other things) by saying "just copy your data then format the drive", problem is i don't have 8tb of drives just laying around (I have a backup of most of the drive but its back at home (read:across the atlantic) and i'd like to continue using the files if i can.

Say i can't repair the file system, how unsafe is it to continue adding/modifying files on this drive so long as i avoid the defunct directory/sub-directories?

Comment: What happens if you let chkdsk finish?  From what you put in there, it looks like it might still be in the process of working...  I suspect there's another bit of information that's missing from this question.

Comment: Removed the shopping/product recommendation bit of your question.

Comment: @Taegost Oops, yeah you are right. I have tried running chkdsk for about 4 hours so far and it does not budge. It just hangs at 75 percent complete. (1 of 996 unindexed files recovered)

Comment: @Karan. Sorry i didn't realize i wasn't allowed to ask for recommendations? (Honestly though, i would happily pay for paidware if it will fix my problem)

Comment: @Gaiko: http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Gaiko, I must have missed something, is the corruption with the Windows 7 machine or the Drobo?